# Can't start with AVD emulator for Galaxy Note 4 (5.0.1)

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to debug a problem with my app (a game made using Unity) on a particular device : Galaxy Note 4 running Android 5.0.1 . The game works fine on other devices. Since my testers are remote, I need to set up a virtual device to debug the problem.

When I create an AVD configuration for this device, the emulator gets stuck on the screen that says "android", and doesn't move on from there.

Here are my settings. I used a skin I downloaded from Samsung's developer site.

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cvKY.png)
[image]

Here's the screen it gets stuck on:
[image]

Has anyone else run into this? How do I get it working? Is anyone aware of an issue with the Galaxy Note 4 when it comes to games? Note that it stopped working when I enabled "multithreaded rendering" in Unity. Works on other devices though.

Edit: adb logcat says this:

```
I/installd( 1612): installd firing up
E/installd( 1612): Could not create directories; exiting.
I/Netd    ( 1610): Netd 1.0 starting
F/appproc ( 1613): Error creating cache dir /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64 : No such file or directory
F/libc    ( 1613): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0x7fb793301f10 in tid 1613 (app_process64)
I/mediaserver( 1611): ServiceManager: 0xf6216d40
I/AudioFlinger( 1611): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
F/appproc ( 1614): Error creating cache dir /data/dalvik-cache/x86 : No such file or directory
F/libc    ( 1614): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf732437c in tid 1614 (app_process32)
I/DEBUG   ( 1380): failed to create /data/tombstones: Read-only file system
I/DEBUG   ( 1380): failed to change ownership of /data/tombstones: No such file or directory
E/DEBUG   ( 1380): Failed to find a valid tombstone, default to using tombstone 0.
E/DEBUG   ( 1380): failed to open tombstone file '/data/tombstones/tombstone_00': No such file or directory
I/DEBUG   ( 1380): Skipping tombstone write, nothing to do.
I/DEBUG   (  949): failed to create /data/tombstones: Read-only file system
I/DEBUG   (  949): failed to change ownership of /data/tombstones: No such file or directory
E/DEBUG   (  949): Failed to find a valid tombstone, default to using tombstone 0.
E/DEBUG   (  949): failed to open tombstone file '/data/tombstones/tombstone_00': No such file or directory
I/DEBUG   (  949): Skipping tombstone write, nothing to do.
```

Comment: change API to - let's say API 17 - and check if it's working

Comment: Hi @piotrek1543, I figured it out - I didn't have a few modules from API 21 installed. I installed them from the SDK manager and its all good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### SOLUTION:

I realized I had not installed some modules from the SDK Manager under the API I wanted. Once I downloaded that, it still wouldn't work until I deleted and re-created the device (Alternatively, I could have chosen the option to wipe the virtual device on start as well I'm sure).

Works now!